# How to get an API URL to take in a dynamic parameter to allow user input?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make `city` a dynamic parameter that will change in my weather app based on which city the user inputs.

I want to pass `city` into the `getWeatherInfo` function. Depending on where I try to assign `city`, I keep getting back errors such as:

- city is undefined,
- city not found, or
- city cannot be accessed before it is initialized.

I cannot see how to make it work. This is my code:

```js
const apiTagUrl = new URL("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + ",USA&units=imperial&appid=" + apiTag);

async function getWeatherInfo() {
  const response = await fetch(apiTagUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
};
getWeatherInfo();
```

Comment: How is your user inputting the city? If it's an input element [maybe add an onChange listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to it that calls the function with the value of the input.

Comment: From what you have posted, it's completely understandable that `city` is undefined as you literally have not included a value for it anywhere, nor do you even have any HTML that is a likely candidate for where to find it.

Comment: Would I know please, where you get the city variable? Also, why do you execute the `getWeatherInfo` function immediately, I think you need to execute it on some type of button submit.

Answer (score 1):

You must put city, like argument to getWeatherInfo function and pass it to string at new URL. Check this code:

```js
 const apiTag = "xxxxxx"

async function getWeatherInfo (city) {
  const apiTagUrl = new URL ("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city +",USA&units=imperial&appid=" + apiTag);
  const response = await fetch (apiTagUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
};

function find(){
  const userValue = document.getElementById("cityInput")
  getWeatherInfo(userValue);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="City..." id="cityInput" />
<button onclick="find()">Get weather</button>
```